# Textarea and objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to display a List inside a TextArea?

```
"NewList":[{"FirstName":"X","LastName":"Y","Address1":"A1","Address2":"A2","City":"C","State":"S","ZipPostalCode":"12345"}, {"FirstName":"X2","LastName":"Y2","Address1":"A2","Address2":"A3","City":"C2","State":"S2","ZipPostalCode":"12345"}]
```

From what I understand, textarea is just used to displaying Text and not HTML, so `<li>` wouldn't work.

Basically, my requirement is to show the above list on the web page and allow the user to Edit and then Save it. 
Can someone please suggest how to do this? Also, how would the form.SerializeObject work with the control we use?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just put each list item in its own text input.

Comment: you mean putting each list item inside a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go through each element and add a `<label>` and an `<input>` for each attribute.

A coding example:

```
response = [{"FirstName":"X","LastName":"Y","Address1":"A1","Address2":"A2","City":"C","State":"S","ZipPostalCode":"12345"}, {"FirstName":"X2","LastName":"Y2","Address1":"A2","Address2":"A3","City":"C2","State":"S2","ZipPostalCode":"12345"}];
form = document.getElementById('formId');
// Iterate through array items
for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
  // Iterate through item attributes
  var item = response[i];
  for(var prop in item){
    // create dom objects
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var input = document.createElement('input');

    // set dom objects attrs
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'field['+i+']['+prop']');
    label.setAttribute('for', 'field['+i+']['+prop']');

    // append items to form
    form.appendChild(label);
    form.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

About serializing the form, are you using [this jQuery plugin](http://danheberden.com/jquery-plugin-serializeobject-2011-04-01/)? I so, you may have to play a little bit with input name to get a useful result.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But the list is dynamic, it could have none, 1 or 20 items inside it. If we add these items to the form as a lable/input combination, its going to be really messy.

Comment: Nope, if you use the plugin I linked before (and try different combinations of input's name attribute), you'll end up having the same array format used at the beginning of the example.